# How to add city drop down in checkout page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

I want to add city drop down in checkout page instead of text field. Searching online couldn't get any solution. Also use this extension https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown ,but this module is not working properly. SO any other solution??

Answer (score 2):

For Frontend:

In layout file checkout_index_index call the template file which has your dropdown html code.it will be displayed on you checkout page.

Code: file name has checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Test\CommunityCommerce\Block\Checkoutmod\Checkoutmod" name="Checkoutmod_Checkoutmod" after="checkout.cart.coupon" template="Sundial_CommunityCommerce::checkout/cart/Checkoutmod.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

In Template file consists :

file name has Checkoutmod.phtml

```
<div class="content" data-role="content" aria-labelledby="block-Checkoutmod-heading">
        <form id="Checkoutmod-form"
              action="#"
              method="post"
              value="0" />
            <?php //echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                         <select id="Checkoutmod_id" name="Checkoutmod_id">                     
                                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                                <option value="test2">test2</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </form>         
    </div>      
</div>
```

Create column in quote table and sales table using setup scripts using "InstallSchema" it will create column into table.

After that using sales_convert_quote and fieldset.xml it will move to quote value to sales table.

Comment: Thanks @Hamendra Sunthwal. But will drop down created for city in address from in checkout page by this code? or it will reate just an extra filed in checkout form?

Comment: This example shows how select field can be created, you can use the method & implement in existing field.